# Navigation through Enter Key

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.4.2.min.js in Firefox browser. If I press enter it navigates to next field, but the blur event alerts are not displayed. This is causing problem, because on Tab key, these messages specified in blur event are displayed. is there any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You're probably returning false or preventing default. Look for one or more of these lines in the code that check for the enter key:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Post the relevant code if you don't know how to fix it.